# Uploading file via URL to YouTube causes "Memory quota exceeded" on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, youtube

I'm trying to upload a file (only S3 URL is available) to YouTube, but the Dyno on Heroku always crashes with an "Memory quota exceeded" error message. I'm afraid the file (or parts of it) are stored in-memory while uploading to YouTube, but don't understand why. Tested locally with a 1GB file and didn't see the memory usage change significantly. Does anyone have a clue, how to fix this and be able to upload files of any size to YouTube without having tons of GB memory on the server?

```
import * as rp from 'request-promise';
const Youtube = require('youtube-api');

function upload(config, credentials, fileUrl) {
    const oauth2 = Youtube.authenticate({
        client_id: config.youtube.clientId,
        client_secret: config.youtube.clientSecret,
        redirect_url: config.youtube.redirectUrl,
        type: 'oauth',
    });

    oauth2.setCredentials(credentials);

    const params = {
        auth: oauth2,
        media: {
            body: rp(fileUrl),
            mimeType: 'application/octet-stream'
        },
        part: 'snippet,status',
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                description: 'my description',
                title: 'my title'
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: 'private'
            }
        },
    };
    Youtube.videos.insert(params, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('success');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found the solution: you just have to integrate the S3 sdk and create a readstream! see below

```
const readStream = s3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream();

const params = {
            auth: oauth2,
            media: {
                body: readStream,
                mimeType: 'video/' + videoFormat
            },
            part: 'snippet,status',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    description: videoProject.shortDescription + videoProject.longDescription,
                    title: title
                },
                status: {
                    privacyStatus: 'private'
                }
            },
        };
```